# how to hide resize bounding lines when exporting an image in konvajs?

Tags: konvajs

I'm building some drag and drop Javascript app using konva.js and I have this one problem:
when i'm exporting the image using the "stage.toDataURL()" command, the exported image contains the resizing boundings: [image: see attached picture]
How can i export the image without the resize bounding lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hide transformer before export, then show it back.

```js
tranformer.hide();
const url = stage.toDataURL():
tranformer.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two layers:

- First layer with nodes
- Second node with transformers

Once you need screenshot without transformers, just use .toDataURI on **First layer**

Layer api: https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Layer.html

[image: React Screenshot]